# BN_is_zero and top==0

Tags: openssl

In OpenSSL,

```
#define BN_is_zero(a)       ((a)->top == 0)
```

I don't get it. I thought it would have been like,

```
#define BN_is_zero(a)       ((a)->top == 1 && (a)->d[0] == 0)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is how OpenSSL define a zero bignum. They don't need to waste a `BN_ULONG`, which is an unsigned long or unsigned long long, to store just zeros. When `top` is 0, the bignum is considered to be zero. You can look at `bn_correct_top(a)`, which is called before `BN_usub()` finish. It will correct `top` to indicate how many `BN_ULONG`s are being used by `a`. When `a` is zero, `bn_correct_top(a)` makes `a->top=0`. Here's an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/bn.h>

void print_r(BIGNUM *r){
    if (BN_is_zero(r)) {
        printf("r is zero\n");
     } else {
        printf("r is ");
        BN_print_fp(stdout,r);
        printf("\n");
     }
}

int main() {
    BIGNUM *r,*a,*b;

    r = BN_new();
    print_r(r);

    a = BN_new();
    b = BN_new();

    BN_dec2bn(&a,"6");
    BN_dec2bn(&b,"6");

    BN_uadd(r,r,a);
    print_r(r);
    BN_usub(r,a,b);
    print_r(r);

    BN_free(r);
    BN_free(a);
    BN_free(b);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
r is zero
r is 6
r is zero
```

Note that after `r = BN_new()`, the bignum `r` is zero since `r->top=0` .